# days to years,months,days conversion doesn't showing the correct result in c

Tags: c, days

```
#include<stdio.h>//Its not showing the correct result//

int main()
{
    int y,m,d;
    scanf("%d",&d);
    y=0;
    m=0;
    y=d/365;
    d=d%365;
    m=d/30;
    d=d%30;
    printf("%d ano(s)\n",&y);
    printf("%d mes(es)\n",&m);
    printf("%d dia(s)\n",&d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of input, what you would expect the program to output, and what it actually outputs instead?

Comment: When I attempt to compile and run this code myself, it points out that `printf` takes with a `"%d"` format string takes `int`s as arguments, not `int*` pointers. Dropping the `&` from the `printf` statements should help. (Although if your problem is, for instance, incorrect handling of leap years or months that are 28 or 31 days long, that obviously won't address it.)

Comment: Out of curiousity, since this is a pain i deal with my quartz wristwatch with dates  all the time, is it possible to account for the 30-31 day variance without knowing what month it is ?

Comment: @APJo Time for a watch that is synced to a time source, perhaps to [WWV](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Sport-Digital-Atomic-Watch/5799667)? or GPS? :-)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica mine is a good ol' analouge , no fancy computation at all, just mechanical precision - needs re-adjustment at the end of every month which has less than 31 days XD ... its a 'fine watch' so i grin and bear it . Another analouge of mine actually also tracks the month and the moon mechanically , so it adjusts itself :)

Comment: Best to keep the one watch then else [uncertainly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal%27s_law).

Answer (score 2):

> conversion doesn't showing the correct result

`m=d/30;` makes sense if all months had 30 days.
They do not unless using another calendar like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Republican_calendar#Months).

Code needs to account for varying amount of days per month and leap years.

---

Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.  Print the value, not the address.

```
// printf("%d ano(s)\n",&y);
// printf("%d mes(es)\n",&m);
// printf("%d dia(s)\n",&d);
printf("%d ano(s)\n", y);
printf("%d mes(es)\n", m);
printf("%d dia(s)\n", d);
```

Comment: maybe Op has confused the way `scanf()` takes arguments with `printf()` ... happened once to me too :)

Comment: @APJo I suspect so too, yet a well enabled compiler gives faster feedback than SO and is hopefully what OP will try for improve productivity.

Comment: Problem is solved. I am new in programming.suggest me the best compiler.I use codeblocks.But it didn't give feedback about this problem.

Comment: @MdMehediHasan since Code::Blocks uses MinGW, you can simply add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow` as options and that will cover just about all warnings. Read and understand each warning and go fix it. Do not accept code until it compiles without warning. You can learn as much from your compiler as you can from just about any good book.